# calculate polynomial with coefficients as abstract class Number

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am struggling with adding operations of classes Natural, Rational, Complex that represent appropriate math objects. I need that to calculate polynomial in x.

All classes inherit abstract class Number. Having all coefficients in an array of Numbers I want to calculate  the polynomial. To do so I need operation of multiplying by double (x is double). x gets transformed into Rational and multiplied. This works fine. My problem is how to add classes of abstract type Number?

I can't make it work. All I get is never ending recursion in Number::add(Number) (it invokes itself instead of invoking others methods for types Natural, Rational, Complex).

#include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```cpp
class Natural;class Rational;class Complex;

class Number {
public:
  virtual string toString() const = 0;
  virtual Number *operator*(const Rational) const = 0;
  virtual Number *add(const Natural*) const = 0;
  virtual Number *add(const Rational*) const = 0;
  virtual Number *add(const Complex*) const = 0;
  virtual Number *add(const Number *n) const {
    n->add(this);
  }
};

class Natural : public Number {
  friend class Complex;
  int n;
public:
  Natural(const Natural &s) {
    n = s.n;
  }
  Natural(int number) : n(number) {}
  string toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << n;
    return ss.str();
  }
  operator Rational() const;
  operator Complex() const;
  operator int() const {
    return n;
  }
  Number *operator*(const Rational r) const;
  Number *add(const Natural* number) const {
    return new Natural(n + number->n);
  }
  Number *add(const Rational*) const;
  Number *add(const Complex*) const;
};

class Rational : public Number {
  friend class Natural;
  int numerator, denominator;
  void divideByGCD() {
    int a = numerator, b = denominator;
    //cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ';
    if(a < b) {
      int temp = a;
      a = b;
      b = temp;
    }
    while (b > 0) {
      int r = a % b;
      a = b; b = r;
      //cout << r << endl;
    }
    numerator /= a;
    denominator /= a;
    //cout << a << endl;
  }
public:
  Rational() {}
  Rational(const Rational &s) {
    numerator = s.numerator;
    denominator = s.denominator;
  }
  Rational(int n, int d) {
    if(d == 0) throw new runtime_error("denominator equals 0");
    if(d < 0) {
      numerator = -n;
      denominator = -d;
    } else {
      numerator = n;
      denominator = d;
    }
    divideByGCD();
  }
  Rational(double d) {
    int i = 0, mul = 1;
    int r = d-floor(d);;
    while(r!=0) {
      i++; mul *= 10;
      r = 10*r-floor(10*r);
    }
    numerator = (int)mul*d;
    denominator = mul;
    divideByGCD();
  }
  string toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << numerator;
    if(denominator > 1) ss << '/' << denominator;
    return ss.str();
  }
  operator const Complex() const;
  operator const double() const {
    return (double)numerator/denominator;
  }
  Number *operator*(const Rational r) const {
    return new Rational(numerator*r.numerator, denominator*r.denominator);
  }
  Number *add(const Rational* r) const {
    return new Rational(numerator*r->denominator+r->numerator*denominator, denominator*r->denominator);
  }
  Number *add(const Natural*) const;
  Number *add(const Complex*) const;
};

class Complex : public Number {
  friend class Rational;
  double real, imaginary;
  static const double radius = 10;
public:
  Complex() {}
  Complex(const Complex &s) {
    real = s.real;
    imaginary = s.imaginary;
  }
  Complex(const double r, const double im) : real(r), imaginary(im) {}
  string toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << real;
    if(imaginary != 0) ss << '+' << imaginary << 'i';
    return ss.str();
  }
  Number *operator*(const Rational r) const;
  Number *add(const Complex* c) const {
    return new Complex(real + c->real, imaginary + c->imaginary);
  }
  Number *add(const Natural*) const;
  Number *add(const Rational*) const;
};

Natural::operator Rational() const {
  return Rational(n,1);
}
Natural::operator Complex() const {
  return Complex(n, 0);
}
Rational::operator const Complex() const {
  return Complex((double)numerator/denominator, 0);
}

Number *Natural::operator*(const Rational r) const {
  return new Rational(n*r.numerator, r.denominator);
}
Number *Complex::operator*(const Rational r) const {
  return new Complex(real*(double)r, imaginary*(double)r);
}

Number *Natural::add(const Rational *r) const {
  if(r->denominator == 1) return new Natural(n+r->numerator);
  else return new Rational(n*r->denominator,r->denominator);
}

Number *Natural::add(const Complex *c) const {
  return c->add(this);
}

Number *Rational::add(const Natural *n) const {
  return n->add(this);
}

Number *Rational::add(const Complex *c) const {
  return new Complex(c->real+(double)*this, c->imaginary);
}

Number *Complex::add(const Natural *number) const {
  return new Complex(real+number->n, imaginary);
}

Number *Complex::add(const Rational *r) const {
  return r->add(this);
}

Number *poly(double x, Number *a[], unsigned int size) {
  if(size == 1) return a[0];
  else return a[0]->add((*poly(x, a+1, size-1))*Rational(x));
}

int main() {
  cout << (Natural(5)*(Rational)2.0)->toString() << endl;

  Number *coefs[] = {new Natural(5), new Natural(6)};
  cout <<  poly(2, coefs, 2) << endl;
}
```

How should I fix Number::add(Number) so that while invoking add on object of type Number program itself figure out which of virtual method add to choose?

Comment: 1st thing I spot is feeling wrong with `Number*` instead of `Number&` returned in the abstract operation definitions.

Comment: that is required. My purpose is to fill in `Number *poly(double,Number**, int)`

Comment: Also a better idea might be a templated approach to declare the `Number` interface, and put appropriate type conversion operators for the concrete Number types.

Comment: I see a lot of `new ...`s, but not a single delete.

Comment: @Rollie: that is standalone programming task not a piece of software to be used. Purpose is one: get the poly() working

Comment: So you are required to keep the signature of poly the same? or the definition as well?

Comment: @Rollie: just signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as multi-dispatch.  Here are some links to look at

[Multiple_dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)

[best multimethods implementation](http://objectmix.com/compilers/747044-best-multimethods-multiple-dispatch-implementations.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

```
virtual Number *add(const Number *n) const {
   n->add(this);
}
```

If you multiply a Rational by a Natural that is stored in a Number *, it can't polymorphicly upcast the Number * to a Natural *.  I agree w/g-makulik in that references/values make a lot more sense here, as you are leaking memory all over the place. Remove support for Number + Number. Also, if I add a Natural and a Rational together, I get a Number * back, but what kind of number is it?  I think the architecture needs a bit more thought; I might get rid of the base class pure virtual methods entirely (except maybe toString). For example:

```
class Number
{
    public:
        virtual string toString() = 0;
};

class Rational : public Number
{
    string toString() {...}
    // forget 'add', use operators
    Rational operator+(const Rational & _rhs) const {Rational ret; ...; return ret;}
    Rational & operator+=(const Rational & _rhs) const {...; return *this;}
    ...
}
```

**Edit**
For a quick fix, I think you just need to get rid of `virtual Number *operator*(const Rational) const = 0;`, and replace it with a version for each sub-class (e.x., `Rational * operator*(const Natural) const`)

Or, add an enumerated member variable to Number to keep track of the type:

```
enum Type { NATURAL, RATIONAL, ...}

Type mType;
```

or use RTTI, such that you can selectively choose the right add method in Number::add:

```
Number * add(Number * _rhs)
{
   if(_rhs->mType == RATIONAL)
      return this->add((Rational *)_rhs);
   ...
}
```

it looks kinda sloppy, but it will work

Comment: I can't get rid of Number class because the point is to remember all information concerning the type in virtual methods.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is what I've been looking for. I wanted to have functions accept and visit in the same class. I believe my mistake was to give them the same name.